# Calculated column- Multiple Conditions Help

Tags: calculated-column

I would like to have a calculated column based producing dates from data in 3 other columns

First column is one of the following: Wave 1, Wave 2, Wave 3, Custom Dates

Second and Thrid Column are dates only for use when Custom Dates is selected to provide said dates.

I'd like to create a set caclulated colume that either:
-produce a start/end date based on the wave selected.
-Or produce the custom start end date provided in the second or third column.

Like this:

[image]

I was trying to figure out a way to use multiple IF conditions like:

=IF([Wave]="Wave 1", "1/1/18"), IF([Wave]="Wave 2", "2/1/18"), IF([Wave]="Custom Dates", "[Custom Start]")

But I couldn't get anything like that to work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

```
=IF(Wave="Wave 1","1/1/2018",IF(Wave="Wave 2","2/1/2018",[Second]))
```

and return type of the calculated column must be set to Date and Time

[image]

[image]

Comment: THANKS!!!  Any idea why mine is producing a date of "12/30/1899" for my rows that have a Wave listed?